# Jquery cant show div by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend, jsfiddle

I have small problem

Here is JSfiddle:
 [link example](http://jsfiddle.net/05fssjvx/)

**HTML CODE**

```
 <body>
<div class="content">
    <!-- Multistep Form -->
    <div class="main">
        <form action="" class="regform" method="get">

            <!-- Progress Bar -->
            <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active">01</li>
                <li>02</li>
                <li>03</li>
        <li>04</li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Fieldsets -->
            <fieldset id="first">
                <h2>press visa or master to go next question</h2>
                <div class="cc-selector">
                    <input id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
                    <label class="kuvake visa jump-next-question" for="visa"></label>
                    <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
                    <label class="kuvake mastercard jump-next-question"for="mastercard"></label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>         


            <fieldset id="second">
                <h2>02 press visa jump fourth question but if press mastercard go next question</h2>
                <div class="cc-selector">
                    <input id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
                    <label class="kuvake visa jump-fourth-question" for="visa"></label>
                    <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
                    <label class="kuvake mastercard jump-next-question"for="mastercard"></label>
                </div>  
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="third">
            <h2>03 press visa or master to go next question</h2>
                <div class="cc-selector">
                    <input id="visa1" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa1" />
                    <label class="kuvake visa1 jump-next-question" for="visa1"></label>
                    <input id="mastercard1" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard1" />
                    <label class="kuvake mastercard1 jump-next-question"for="mastercard1"></label>
                </div>
                <input class="next_btn" name="next" type="button" value="Next">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="fourth">
            <h2>04</h2>
                <div class="cc-selector">
                    <input id="visa2" type="radio" name="visa2" value="visa2" />
                    <label class="kuvake visa2" for="visa2"></label>
                    <input id="mastercard2" type="radio" name="master2" value="mastercard2" />
                    <label class="kuvake mastercard2"for="mastercard2"></label>
                </div>
                <input class="next_btn" name="next" type="button" value="Next">
            </fieldset>


        </form>
```

**jQuery code**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".jump-next-question").click(function() { // Function Runs On NEXT Button Click
        $(this).closest('fieldset').next().fadeIn('slow');
        $(this).closest('fieldset').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    // Adding Class Active To Show Steps Forward;
    $('.active').next().addClass('active');
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".jump-fourth-question").click(function() { // Function Runs On NEXT Button Click
        $(this).closest('jump-fourth-question').next().fadeIn('slow');
        $(this).closest('fieldset').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    // Adding Class Active To Show Steps Forward;
    $('.active').next().addClass('active');
    });

});
```

I have small demo quiz, and I need to get questions go to next answer and that works ok, but when we are question number two if you answer visa you should jump to the question number fourth and show it but it wont work.

Any help here?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't subvert the 'code in the question' rule. It exists for a reason; link rot. If jsFiddle goes down your question will be unanswerable, and also useless for any future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is due to `.closest()` in click event of class `.jump-fourth-question`.Since you are searching for closest with same class name it is redirecting to `02` again and you are using `display:none` for it.So you are not getting any result.

The other problem is you are using document `$(document).ready(function(){});` twice.Avoid ding that.

Your Jquery should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".jump-next-question").click(function() { // Function Runs On NEXT Button Click
    $(this).closest('fieldset').next().fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).closest('fieldset').css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    // Adding Class Active To Show Steps Forward;
    $('.active').next().addClass('active');
  });


  $(".jump-fourth-question").click(function() { // Function Runs On NEXT Button Click
    $(this).closest('fieldset').next().next().fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).closest('fieldset').css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    // Adding Class Active To Show Steps Forward;
    $('.active').next().next().addClass('active');
  });

});
```

EDIT:

Yes you can directly use the `id` `#fourth`

```
$(".jump-fourth-question").click(function() { 
    $('#fourth').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Just in intrest, is it possible to search and show it by the fieldset id? like (".jump-fourth-question").click and show fieldset by id

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you use a wrong selector.
You are selecting to show/hide the button instead of the fieldset itself.

here is a working example :
`.   http://jsbin.com/filaluhiti/edit?css,js,console,output`

PS : You only need one occurence of "Document ready"

Comment: Awsome! Thank you!